# Making TextView Scrollable in Android programmatically

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I want to make `textView` programmatically and make them scrollable. I am calling this method again and again to get `textView` and adding it to the `linearLayout`.

```
TextView textView = addTextView(contents.paragraphs.get(i),false);
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

But, it is not scrollable at all. The method is:

```
private TextView addTextView(String text,boolean type) {
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText(text);
        valueTV.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPrimary));
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        valueTV.setMaxLines(1000);
        valueTV.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        valueTV.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        return valueTV;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

If you use `WRAP_CONTENT` the `TextView` will increase height 'indefinitely'.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `TextView` into a `ScrollView`

```
 ViewGroup linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
 TextView textView = addTextView(contents.paragraphs.get(i), false);
 ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
 scroller.addView(textView);
 linearLayout.addView(scroller);
```